# In which order do the hooks set by SetWindowsHookEx() receive messages?

Tags: winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

If application A calls SetWindowsHookEx() to insert a low-level mouse hook (WH_MOUSE_LL) and application B does the same afterwards, which will receive a message first?

Comment: Application A, which should then call `CallNextHookEx` to pass it to the next app hook. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa)

Comment: Application B receive the message first. @IInspectable is right. Feel free let me know if you still have any concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is documented under [Hooks Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks):

> The [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) function **always installs a hook procedure at the beginning of a hook chain**. When an event occurs that is monitored by a particular type of hook, the system calls the procedure at the beginning of the hook chain associated with the hook. Each hook procedure in the chain determines whether to pass the event to the next procedure. A hook procedure passes an event to the next procedure by calling the [CallNextHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callnexthookex) function.

In your example, hook B will receive the message first, because it was installed most recent.